# Raising an event from inner class to be handled at outer class, How to Do?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, class, inner-classes

I have a class A, B

```
    class A
    {
        public class B
        {
            public event EventHandler handleClick;
            public void eventraising(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (handleClick != null)
                    handleClick(this, e);
            }
        }

        //handle raised event here
    }
```

How can I do this

Comment: By the way, the best practices say that your event should be called Click (see other comment below), your eventraising method should be called OnClick and be virtual so that it can be overriden by a child class. You also don't need the sender parameter since you are passing this to your event handler (a good thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class A would need an *instance* of B somewhere first. Nesting classes in .NET is simply a way of organizing the types. It doesn't imply any kind of ownership of an instance.

So you'd have to do something like:

```
class A
{

    private B instanceOfB;

    // constructor
    public A() {
        instanceOfB = new B();
        instanceOfB.handleClick += instanceOfB_handleClick;
    }

    // event handler
    private void instanceOfB_handleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // blah
    }

    public class B
    {
        public event EventHandler handleClick;
        public void eventraising(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (handleClick != null)
                handleClick(this, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Also, your event should just be called Click, not handleClick.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of B in A.

```
class A
{
    B b = new B;

    A()
    {
        b.handleClick += (sender, ev) => { ... }
    }
}
```